# Developing a multiple client one server application Android

Tags: android, tcp

I want to develop an application that has socket connection with many clients or Android devices connected to one Android device as the server with TCP connection. The server receives information (name, IP address, device name) from the clients and saves it to the database.

Once the information was saved, the server will send a message to the clients and show the clients the list saved in the database (name, IP address, device name).

I'm new with socket programming and I want to implement KyroNet library that is working for Android too. Can anyone help me give a sample code to get started with this project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the KyroNet library, but you should look at the BluetoothChat example application provided with Android.  Bluetooth sockets are just about the same as a regular socket, so it should be nearly identical code-wise.  The app also shows how to implement a Handler and Thread for the connections.

Comment: i also come up with that solution but as i consult it with my team, bluetooth has a limited range and time for connectivity

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I'm not recommending to use Bluetooth, just that you should use the BluetoothChat application as a reference to your project because programming a BluetoothSocket is very similar to programming a Socket.  I know it was handy for me when I created a simple TCP client/server app.

Comment: does it support multiple clients?